# Spring-Data-Neo4J: How do I save a property on a relationship?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I created an `@RelationshipEntity` called `HasContact`. I instantiate and create a new `HasContact` relationship as such:

```
HasContact adminClerk = new HasContact (company, employee, "Admin Clerk")
template.save (adminClerk);
```

My `RelationshipEntity` class looks like this:

```
@RelationshipEntity(type="HAS_CONTACT")
public class HasContact {

    @GraphId
    Long id;

    @StartNode
    Company company;

    @EndNode
    Employee employee;

    String role;

    public HasContact() {
        // Empty Constructor
    }

    public HasContact(Company company, Employee employee, String role) {
        this.company = company
        this.employee = employee
        this.role = role;
    }

    /*** Gettes and Setters ***/

    ...
}
```

In the above simple example, the relationship is persisted, by the role property on the relationship is not. Any ideas why not, and how I can resolve this?

Comment: Which version of SDN, and if 4.0, are you using the 4.0.0.M1 release or snapshot?

Comment: I'm using 3.0.0 - Should I be moving to 4.0.0.M1

Comment: Just asked because I can help you with 4, but not very much with 3, sorry :-)

Comment: Are you using embedded or remote? And is it really 3.0.0 or perhaps 3.3.0 ?

Comment: @Michael is this a kniwn bug of version 3.3.0

Answer (score 1):

**I suspect that this is a bug in the 3.x codebase**-- I'm running into the same issue, and I've spent about a half-day trying to track this down.

My setup id using SpringBoot and Spring 4.1.6 with Neo-Data 3.3.0.RELEASE (and then 3.4.0.M1).  There have been some problems apparently with 4.1.6 Spring and this is my first project with Neo4j, so it's possible I'm missing something and would be happy to have someone tell me what I'm missing...

What I observe is that for a single relationship entity being saved, there are double writes to the *actual Neo4j db* -- the first one sets properties correctly, and the second one erases all the "extra" properties.

Please reference the below excerpt from SourceStateTransmitter.java (3.4.0.M1) is that the properties get set correctly (around line 102/105) and are then overwritten by the UpdateableState flush on line 109.

```
   101 // todo take mapping policies for attributes into account
   102    persistentEntity.doWithProperties(new PropertyHandler<Neo4jPersistentProperty>() {
   103      @Override
   104      public void doWithPersistentProperty(Neo4jPersistentProperty property) {
   105          setEntityStateValue(property, entityState, wrapper, property.getMappingPolicy());
   106      }
   107    });
   108    if (target instanceof UpdateableState) {
   109       ((UpdateableState)target).flush();
   110    }
```

E.g. after line 105, inspecting the Neo4j database shows relationships with properties as desired, but once line 109 executes-- it overwrites the newly created entity with a map that has exactly one property (the relationship type).

I tried recreating as a test using the latest 3.x version from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j -- however, the tests I tried were using the ImpermanentGraphDatabase which is not equivalent in this case.

When the protocol involves communication to an actual Neo4j database, the entityStateHandler.useOrCreateState() ends up creating 2 objects that have different property maps to write to the relationship.  The relationship properties end up being written correctly to one map (e.g. in relation to the writes associated with lines 102-105)-- but that one is disjoint from the property map that is contained/used when the target is flushed on line 109 (which is empty beyond the basic relationship-type/label information).

When the protocol involves the ImpermanentGraphDatabase, I assume it ends up with a shared instance (e.g. both creation steps produce the same object-- in memory vs. actual REST communication with an endpoint) and therefore there is no consistency problem.

So I haven't been able to produce a test case that breaks this, but I'm still reasonably sure that this is a bug.  As I'm new to Spring-Data-Neo4j, I'm sure there could be things I'm missing though.

(Hmm.. wonder if this works better in 4.0-- which isn't mentioned here http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/.  But as there is a new rewrite that seems to be where the future is, not sure if this will get fixed)

Comment: Thanks for the great analysis. I came to the same conclusion, that's why I added a mechanism, so that both instances should be the same now in 3.3.1. Did you try that version?

Comment: @MichaelHunger, I tested this back in June on the 3.3.0 version before the 3.3.1 branch was released.   I tried verifying today that 3.3.1 fixed it  from the branch I explored this issue on-- but that didn't work.  Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I've always successfully saved relationships with attributes calling the *relateTo* method on one of the edge endpoints, i.e. :

```
HasContact hasContact = company.relateTo(employee, HasContact.class, "HAS_CONTACT");

hasContact.setRole("Admin Clerk");
```